# Datatable Checkbox Return Empty

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using Datatable Checkbox from https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/.
I have followed instructions, but I array selected is not returned. 
Javascript Codes:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var tableuser = $("#user_table").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url"  : "http://flazengine-new.local/table-data-new",
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "async": true,
                    "data" : {
                                        "field":["user_f_id","user_f_name","user_f_phone","user_f_email","user_f_status","user_group_f_name"],                                                  "searchs":["user_f_name","user_f_phone","user_f_email","user_f_status","user_group_f_name"],                                                    "id":"ZFhObGNsOW1YMmxr",                                                    "key":"0",                                                  "ids":"0",                                                  "table":"Wm1WZmRYTmxjZz09",                                                 "module":"user",                                                    "query":"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}}",                                                 "bind":"0",                                                 "modal":"1",                                                    "edit":"1",                                                 "delete":"1",                                                   "divider":"0",                                                  "action":"0",                                                   "modals":"0",                                                   "modal_file":"0",                                                   },
                    "type": "POST",
                    "complete" : function(){
                    },
                    "error" : function (xhr, error, thrown){
                        console.log(xhr);
                    }
                },
                "destroy": false,
                "language": {
                    "lengthMenu"    : "Menampilkan _MENU_ record per halaman",
                    "zeroRecords"   : "Tabel Kosong",
                    "info"          : "Memunculkan halaman _PAGE_ dari _PAGES_",
                    "infoEmpty"     : "Tidak ada data ditemukan.",
                    "infoFiltered"  : "(ditemukan _MAX_ jumlah records)",
                    "processing"    : "Proses menampilkan data...",
                },
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "searchDelay": null,
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        'targets': 0,
                        'checkboxes': {
                            'selectRow': true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        widthuser                                       
                    }
                ],
                "select": {
                    'style': 'multi'
                },
                'order': [[1, 'asc']]                           
            });
            window.showdata     = function(){
                var selecteduser = tableuser.columns(0).checkboxes.selected();
                var itemselecteduser = [];
                $.each(selecteduser, function(index, rowId){
                    itemselecteduser.push(rowId);
                });
                console.log(itemselecteduser);
            }
});
```

Here is my Data:

```
    {
"draw":1,
"recordsTotal":3,
"recordsFiltered":3,
"data":
    [
        [
            "TkRjd0lDQWdJQ0FnSUNBZ0lDQWdJQ0FnSUNBZ0lDQWdJQ0FnSUNBZ0lDQWdJQ0Fn",
            1,
            "Administrator",
            "123456",
            "admin@aku.com",
            "Active",
            "Administrator",
            "<div class='btn-group'> <div class='btn btn-success btn-sm' onclick='getdatauser(\"470 \")' role='button' data-toggle='modal' title='Ubah' data-target='#addDatauser'><i class='fa fa-edit'><\/i><\/div> <div class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' role='button' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Hapus' id='delete470 '><i class='fa fa-remove'><\/i><\/div> <script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#user_table tbody').on('click','#delete470 ',function(e){ var href = $(this).attr('href'); swal({ title: 'Delete Data?', type: 'warning', showCancelButton: true, confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55', confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Delete!', cancelButtonText: 'No, Cancel!', closeOnConfirm: true, closeOnCancel: true }, function (isConfirm){ if (isConfirm){ $.ajax({ type: 'POST', async: false, url: 'http:\/\/flazengine-new.local\/user-delete', data: {table:'Wm1WZmRYTmxjZz09',where:'ZFhObGNsOW1YMmxr',id:'TkRjd0lDQWdJQ0FnSUNBZ0lDQWdJQ0FnSUNBZ0lDQWdJQ0FnSUNBZ0lDQWdJQ0Fn'}, cache: false, dataType: 'json', success: function(res){ if(res['status'] === 'success'){ console.log('Status Nih: '+res['status']); $('#user_table').DataTable().ajax.reload(); }else{ alert(res['message']); } } }); } }); return false; }); }); <\/script> <\/div>"
        ],
        [
            "T0dReU1qa3pOMlF0TW1FMk1TMDBNV1ptTFdGa016VXRPVEl6Wm1KallXVm1OalJp",
            2,
            "COBA LAGI AJAH",
            "123456",
            "coba@coba.com",
            "Active",
            "Administrator",
            "<div class='btn-group'> <div class='btn btn-success btn-sm' onclick='getdatauser(\"8d22937d-2a61-41ff-ad35-923fbcaef64b\")' role='button' data-toggle='modal' title='Ubah' data-target='#addDatauser'><i class='fa fa-edit'><\/i><\/div> <div class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' role='button' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Hapus' id='delete8d22937d-2a61-41ff-ad35-923fbcaef64b'><i class='fa fa-remove'><\/i><\/div> <script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#user_table tbody').on('click','#delete8d22937d-2a61-41ff-ad35-923fbcaef64b',function(e){ var href = $(this).attr('href'); swal({ title: 'Delete Data?', type: 'warning', showCancelButton: true, confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55', confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Delete!', cancelButtonText: 'No, Cancel!', closeOnConfirm: true, closeOnCancel: true }, function (isConfirm){ if (isConfirm){ $.ajax({ type: 'POST', async: false, url: 'http:\/\/flazengine-new.local\/user-delete', data: {table:'Wm1WZmRYTmxjZz09',where:'ZFhObGNsOW1YMmxr',id:'T0dReU1qa3pOMlF0TW1FMk1TMDBNV1ptTFdGa016VXRPVEl6Wm1KallXVm1OalJp'}, cache: false, dataType: 'json', success: function(res){ if(res['status'] === 'success'){ console.log('Status Nih: '+res['status']); $('#user_table').DataTable().ajax.reload(); }else{ alert(res['message']); } } }); } }); return false; }); }); <\/script> <\/div>"
        ],
        [
            "TURRMU9UQXlZalV0TmpZeU55MDBPVE0wTFRnNVpqZ3RNVFF3TURGbFltUXlNV1Zt",
            3,
            "APA AJAH",
            "123456",
            "apaajah@apaajah.com",
            "Active",
            "Administrator",
            "<div class='btn-group'> <div class='btn btn-success btn-sm' onclick='getdatauser(\"045902b5-6627-4934-89f8-14001ebd21ef\")' role='button' data-toggle='modal' title='Ubah' data-target='#addDatauser'><i class='fa fa-edit'><\/i><\/div> <div class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' role='button' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Hapus' id='delete045902b5-6627-4934-89f8-14001ebd21ef'><i class='fa fa-remove'><\/i><\/div> <script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#user_table tbody').on('click','#delete045902b5-6627-4934-89f8-14001ebd21ef',function(e){ var href = $(this).attr('href'); swal({ title: 'Delete Data?', type: 'warning', showCancelButton: true, confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55', confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Delete!', cancelButtonText: 'No, Cancel!', closeOnConfirm: true, closeOnCancel: true }, function (isConfirm){ if (isConfirm){ $.ajax({ type: 'POST', async: false, url: 'http:\/\/flazengine-new.local\/user-delete', data: {table:'Wm1WZmRYTmxjZz09',where:'ZFhObGNsOW1YMmxr',id:'TURRMU9UQXlZalV0TmpZeU55MDBPVE0wTFRnNVpqZ3RNVFF3TURGbFltUXlNV1Zt'}, cache: false, dataType: 'json', success: function(res){ if(res['status'] === 'success'){ console.log('Status Nih: '+res['status']); $('#user_table').DataTable().ajax.reload(); }else{ alert(res['message']); } } }); } }); return false; }); }); <\/script> <\/div>"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Datatable Picture:
[Datatable Checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR6gQ.png)

Result of Console.log:
[Result of Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAZjm.png)

I need to return selected row of datatable. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

In your context you need to use `column(0).checkboxes.selected()` instead of `columns(0).checkboxes.selected()`. Return value of API method `columns()` differs from `column()`.